# Can inet_pton and inet_ntop UNIX functions be really locale dependent?

Tags: c, linux, unix, locale

In https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/10771#discussion_r1130059596 I was pointed out that `inet_pton` and `inet_ntop` UNIX functions can be locale dependent as they are documented so.

However, the output format of these functions is well defined so my question is, are they really locale dependent and can someone point me to a configuration/library where they have non-standard format?

Comment: That person at the Github thread seems confused. Maybe they are confusing "locale" with "implementation-defined behavior" (compiler/system specific). IP headers are big endian so there might be endianess related issues, but that's implementation-defined behavior, not locale-related. The only thing that I can up with as actual locale-specific is some (northern Europe) counties using `,` for decimals, but I've never seen that used for IP numbers over dot `.` and then I live in such a country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The threat you linked has a bad interpretation of `MT-Safe locale`. It is about type of safety, not about locale/culture/etc.

But it is also possible both functions depend on *locale*: if I remember correctly the only condition about charset is that `\0` and `/` are fixed (and `C` has a requirement that digits `0` to `9` use consecutive encoding values). And each locale can defin own charset. In any case, I think most program just assume ASCII (or a subset of ASCII). But it is so seldom that I'm not sure I interpret `LC_TYPE` correctly. Maybe there is stronger assumption on charset in POSIX.

And you can make both function portable. The non-portable way is was just a shortcut: if you know the structure of long and of each byte of the IP (as in IP packets) you could have a optimized version. But since many years (few decades) compilers will optimize also the portable code.

Comment: The only reasonably common encodings that don't share the same byte values for ASCII digits are UTF-16/UCS-2 and UTF-32/UCS-4. Neither of which are really in use as encodings for any \*nix locales because they mess up the whole "strings are null-terminated" property. The only encodings that I can think of that have different encodings and *would* work on a *nix are EBCDIC and its variants, but I've not seen that used in a long, long time.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: EBCDIC cannot be used in Unix (digits are non-consecutive). But you can define your own locale (and just locally to you)... but ip functions will not be the first problem if somebody will do it. OTOH C (and other standards) are starting to stop support of odd machines.

Comment: Didn't know that unix requires consecutive digits, but either way, EBCDIC is (deservedly) mostly a historical footnote by now.

Comment: Simply said, excluding a custom locale that does not make sense for UNIX, the ip2long/long2ip output will be always the same (and thus can be cached) in the same running UNIX process even if the locale is changed, am I right?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi *EBCDIC cannot be used in Unix (digits are non-consecutive)*  [Yes they are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) - EBCDIC digits are `F0` through `F9`.  [It's the C language that requires digits to be represented consecutirvely](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1p3): "In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous."

Comment: @AndrewHenle: you are right. The reason was about `/` which was in different places. (and maybe other reasons, but I remember that EBCDIC was not allowable in Posix).

Comment: @mvorisek: if you change it within your program (and maybe in an other thread), the output may change. (but so it is in your control). But you are right, or better: locales are just set as hint in environment variables (so they cannot be changed externally on a running process), and it is process task to choose if and how to use it.